# Intercept traffic from a RJ45 TV box

Tags: networking, proxy, http, wireshark

I'm using a box that connects to the internet using an RJ45 cable. I would like to see the HTTP traffic that goes in and out the box.

Would you plug a computer to the same network and run Wireshark, or is it easier to interpret the traffic if I set the laptop as bridge between the box and a wireless internet for example.

Is there a reason that makes an option better than the other?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any of the mentioned options and they didn't work ?

Comment: If you have a network switch, you won't be able to plug a computer in and run wireshark because the TV box traffic won't go to the computer at all. For that you would need a switch with a management option for 'port mirroring', or an older style hub.

Comment: So is this box a cable modem?  Those "connect to the Internet" by connecting to the TV cable coming into the house, which generally doesn't involve RJ45.  Or is it some a DSL (ADSL, VDSL, etc.) modem?  Those tend to connect to a telephone wire, which usually involves RJ11 rather than RJ45.  Or is it some other type of box?  Or is the RJ45 connection the way it allows *other* wired devices to connect to the Internet?

Comment: @SeanClt I'm actually trying to compare options for now and understand theoretically the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The laptop and the box connect to a router.

Comment: @GuyHarris I shouldn't have said box, it's like one of those android boxes that connect to a server that sends it a list of streams that it can play.

Comment: The simplest connection would be an Ethernet hub, which I've purchased used from eBay for $10-15.  The hub allows a simple "T" connection to intercept the traffic.  There's a Wireshark page on hubs that are known to work, i.e. some "hubs" are actually switches.

Comment: OK, so it's a "TV box" in that it plugs into a TV and plays streaming content from the Internet on it, and plugs into a cable modem or DSL modem or other Internet access device over an Ethernet cable (which would have ["RJ45"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C) plugs on both ends), and you want to capture the HTTP traffic that goes over that cable?

Comment: @GuyHarris Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is really just "I have a machine with a wired Ethernet connection to my {cable modem, DSL modem, other Internet access box, router that plugs into the cable modem/DSL modem/other Internet access box}; what's the best way to capture its traffic to the Internet?"

The device that your TV box is plugged into probably has multiple Ethernet ports, and acts as a switch between those ports; you could plug another computer into it, but that means you have the problem that @TessellatingHeckler mentioned - yes, it's a router between the wireless and wired connections to it and the Internet, but the wired connections are almost certainly part of a switch internal to the box, and it's probably *not* a switch with any form of "port mirroring".

So your only options are probably to use a hub, and plug the TV box and laptop into it and plug the hub into the port into which the TV box used to be plugged, or to use the laptop as a bridge between the TV box and the device it was plugged into.  Plugging the laptop into the same network as the TV box - i.e., plugging it into the switch inside the box in question - won't let you see the TV box's traffic from the laptop.

Doing it with a hub, as per @sawdust's suggestion, is probably easier than configuring your laptop as a bridge.

For a long technical boring discussion, see [the Wireshark Wiki's page on capturing Ethernet traffic](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet).